# Database Design for student tracking system

Tags: database, erd

EDIT: my revised Entity relationship diagram
A Student can have many contact times but this does not relate to what course they are on. So the courseID in tblContact was unnecessary, so I used to Primary keys in tblStudent relating to the grade for a particular tutor marked assignment and the course a particular student is on with that TMA.
Phew

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wn5jb.png

/Edit

My **Old** ERD

[image: ERD]

note that StudID and CourseID are a merged compound primary key

My question: Should I have studID and courseID in tblContact? or should I just have StudID, because I'm using a compound primary key I thought I should have both values in tblContact and tblStudentTMA?
Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on whether the contact is related to a course or not.

If it relates to a course then you need some way of identifying the Course from the contact, but you can link to the tblCourse table from tblContact.

My preference for a many-many table is to use a separate primary key in your example `StudentCourseID`, which is a [Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_column) column, this removes the need to store multiple foreign keys in a related table.

Answer (score 0):

The primary key in tblContact has to have at least two columns. One of them has to be StudID.

It has to have at least two columns, because you need to store more than one contact per student. One of the columns has to be StudID to guarantee the contact row refers to an actual student.  The second column probably needs to be DateOfContact.

A primary key {StudID, DateOfContact} allows one contact per student per day. If you use {StudID, TimeOfContact} instead--use a timestamp instead of a date--you can have more than one contact per student per day.

In addition to that, if *every* row in tblContact must refer to both a student and to one of that student's courses, then you should probably include CourseID in the primary key. You also need a foreign key reference from tblContact (StudID, CourseID) to tblStudentCourse (StudID, CourseID).

If it's not necessary for every row in tblContact to refer to a course, then tblContact.CourseID should be nullable, and it shouldn't be part of the primary key.  But you should still have a foreign key reference from tblContact (StudID, CourseID) to tblStudentCourse (StudID, CourseID).

Comment: First question is: My opinion was that you didn't need primary keys in tables with no children. Because you wouldn't be referring to them, so does you first sentence need to occur?

Comment: Every table needs either a primary key or its equivalent. In a SQL database, declaring a column `NOT NULL UNIQUE` is equivalent to declaring it `PRIMARY KEY`.  Keys have to do with identity, not with whether other tables reference the keys.  Loosely speaking, every SQL table needs some way to identify each row. The SQL way is with a key. (Either `NOT NULL UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY`.)